# getting "WARNING: No match found for input: load aiml b" with all files in the same directory

Tags: python, chatbot, aiml

So i wanted to try to make a chatbot for python, i put all the needed files for aiml in the same directory yet i still get the "WARNING: No match found for input: load aiml b" error.

Here is the contents of the python file

```
import aiml

kernel = aiml.Kernel()
kernel.learn("std-startup.xml")
kernel.respond("load aiml b")

while True:
  input_text = input("Human: ")
  response = kernel.respond(input_text)
  print("Bot:" +response)
```

the contents of the xml file

```
<aiml version="1.0.1" encoding="UTF-8">

<category>

<pattern>load aiml b</pattern>
<template>
  <learn>basic_chat.aiml</learn>
</template>

</category>

</aiml>
```

and the contents of the basic aiml file i created

```
<aiml version="1.0.1" encoding="UTF-8">

<category>
<pattern>
Hello
</pattern>

<template>
Hello User
</template>

</category>

<category>
<pattern>
What are you?
</pattern>

<template>
I am a bot
</template>

</category>

</aiml>
```

Comment: This code should work if you have updated all patterns to upper case. Are you sure the xml and aiml are in the same directory as the python script (not subdirectory)?

Answer (score -1):

A quick search says that you need the pattern in capital letters:

```
<category>
    <pattern>LOAD AIML B</pattern>
    <template>
        <learn>basic.aiml</learn>
    </template>
</category>
```

Comment: I updated the pattern to capital letters and it's still outputting the same error.

Answer (score -1):

try typing an asterisk after hello, like that:

HELLO *